# Eclipse not installing most recent version of code

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

when i compile my android app to test on android device the first time, it installs the app on the device, but after changing some code when i recompile the code from eclipse ,the device runs the first installed version of the app.

please help me out.

Comment: Are you using motodev? Eclipse?

Comment: Removed anroid-emulator tag as it doesn't apply to a device question

Answer (score 0):

some times such problem occur, try uninstalling then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you should be checking for:

- Make sure you install the update, and not just compile it
- Make sure the update is signed with the same certificate. Otherwise it will not install
- Make sure your device is connected and USB debugging is enabled.
- Try uninstalling the app from the device before pushing the update.

You can check to see if the install succeeded or failed in the console.